# Проверка расширения файла

Tags: php, файлы, безопасность, загрузка

При загрузки файлов на сервер нужно разрешить только определенный типы файлов
а именно .pdf,.doc,docx,.xml,xls,.rtf,.dot,.txt,.png,.gif,.tif,.bmp,image/*

Загружаются с помощью  инпута

```
<input name="upfile_101" type="file" multiple="multiple" accept=".pdf,.doc,docx,.xml,xls,.rtf,.dot,.txt,.png,.gif,.tif,.bmp,image/*">
```

Как понимаю, надо это делать на сервере в этом файле. но как с чего начать?

```html
<?php

if( isset( $_POST['my_file_upload'] ) ){  
    // ВАЖНО! тут должны быть все проверки безопасности передавемых файлов и вывести ошибки если нужно
    

    $uploaddir = '../../../uploads'; // . - текущая папка где находится submit.php
    
    // cоздадим папку если её нет
    if( ! is_dir( $uploaddir ) ) mkdir( $uploaddir, 0777 );

    $files      = $_FILES; // полученные файлы
    $done_files = array();

    // переместим файлы из временной директории в указанную
    foreach( $files as $file ){
        $file_name = cyrillic_translit( $file['name'] );
        
        ////START////
        $pathinfo = pathinfo($file_name);
        $file_name = $pathinfo['filename'].'_'.time();
    
        $file_name .= '.'.$pathinfo['extension'];
        $file_name = strtolower($file_name);
        ////END////

        if( move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], "$uploaddir/$file_name" ) ){
            $done_files[] = realpath( "$uploaddir/$file_name" );
        }
    }
    
    $data = $done_files ? array('files' => $done_files ) : array('error' => 'Ошибка загрузки файлов.');
    
    die( json_encode( $data ) );
}


## Транслитирация кирилических символов
function cyrillic_translit( $title ){
    $iso9_table = array(
        'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V', 'Г' => 'G', 'Ѓ' => 'G',
        'Ґ' => 'G', 'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E', 'Ё' => 'YO', 'Є' => 'YE',
        'Ж' => 'ZH', 'З' => 'Z', 'Ѕ' => 'Z', 'И' => 'I', 'Й' => 'J',
        'Ј' => 'J', 'І' => 'I', 'Ї' => 'YI', 'К' => 'K', 'Ќ' => 'K',
        'Л' => 'L', 'Љ' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N', 'Њ' => 'N',
        'О' => 'O', 'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R', 'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T',
        'У' => 'U', 'Ў' => 'U', 'Ф' => 'F', 'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'TS',
        'Ч' => 'CH', 'Џ' => 'DH', 'Ш' => 'SH', 'Щ' => 'SHH', 'Ъ' => '',
        'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ь' => '', 'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'YU', 'Я' => 'YA',
        'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'ѓ' => 'g',
        'ґ' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'yo', 'є' => 'ye',
        'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'ѕ' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'j',
        'ј' => 'j', 'і' => 'i', 'ї' => 'yi', 'к' => 'k', 'ќ' => 'k',
        'л' => 'l', 'љ' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'њ' => 'n',
        'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's', 'т' => 't',
        'у' => 'u', 'ў' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'ts',
        'ч' => 'ch', 'џ' => 'dh', 'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'shh', 'ъ' => '',
        'ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya'
    );

    $name = strtr( $title, $iso9_table );
    $name = preg_replace('~[^A-Za-z0-9\'_\-\.]~', '-', $name );
    $name = preg_replace('~\-+~', '-', $name ); // --- на -
    $name = preg_replace('~^-+|-+$~', '', $name ); // кил - на концах

    return $name;
}
```

Нашел решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166762/php-image-upload-security-check-list

Мне достаточно 1 пункта 
Отключите PHP от запуска внутри папки загрузки с помощью .htaccess

```
hp_flag engine 0
RemoveHandler .phtml .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .phps .cgi .exe .pl .asp .aspx .shtml .shtm .fcgi .fpl .jsp .htm .html .wml
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phtml .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .phps .cgi .exe .pl .asp .aspx .shtml .shtm .fcgi .fpl .jsp .htm .html .wml
```

Comment: проверка расширения файла не спасет вас от реальной загрузки произвольных данных

Comment: Проверка расширения хотя бы спасет от загрузки вредоносных скриптов и их дальнейшего запуска. вот только как проверять файлы?

Answer (score 1):

можно создать массив с правилами, и затем циклом делать проверку вроде "если расширение принятого файла не равняется значению из массива, то выбросить ошибку"

Comment: Anton Kucenko - массив с правилами это хорошо. но как? не поделитеть скриптом?

Comment: скрипта нету, но выглядит примерно так

`$rules = ['jpg', 'png'];

foreach($rules as $k => $v){
    if('расширение файла ' != $v){
          return false;
    }else return true;
}`

Comment: $rules -  это переменная содержащая файл?  у меня есть $files - это   $rules?

Comment: $rules это массив который содержит указанные вами расширения (которые дозволены для данного файла)

Comment: Хорошо, а как теперь этот массив сопоставлять с моим загруженными файлами?

Comment: Нашел решение, прям мой случай
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166762/php-image-upload-security-check-list

мне достаточно 1 пункта 
Отключите PHP от запуска внутри папки загрузки с помощью .htaccess
Прописать в нем:
hp_flag engine 0
RemoveHandler .phtml .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .phps .cgi .exe .pl .asp .aspx .shtml .shtm .fcgi .fpl .jsp .htm .html .wml
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phtml .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .phps .cgi .exe .pl .asp .aspx .shtml .shtm .fcgi .fpl .jsp .htm .html .wml

Comment: $fileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));  В $target_file - тут имя файла, $fileType - тут получите его расширение. Дальше сравнивайте с массивом разрешенных расширений.